# Sum of all elements of a Set

Tags: number-theory, summation

Let's say I want to determine the number of natural numbers for an $x \in N$ this particular way: $$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^x a\in\lbrace 1 : x\space\mathbf {mod}\space i=0\rbrace$$Is this the correct way to express this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to determine? The size of a set? If so, let $A$ be your set. Then $|A| = \sum_{a\in A} 1$.

Comment: Given your edit, it seems you're trying to determine the sum of all elements in the set: this is $\sum_{a\in A} a$.

Comment: @Unit I think the OP wants the number of divisors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want $f(x)$ to be the result of adding $1$ for each $1\leq i\leq x$ such that $x\equiv 0\bmod i$, then you are counting the number of divisors of $x$, and it is usually denoted $d(x)$ or $\sigma_0(x)$.

One is allowed to be much more expressive in the range of a sum than just the numbers from a start to a finish value. It's not uncommon to see expressions like
$$\sum_{\large \substack{(x,y)\in A\cap B\\ x<5\\
\sin(y)<0}}\cdots$$
Therefore a much easier way of writing what you want is
$$\sum_{d\mid n}$$
where the notation $d\mid n$ means "$d$ divides $n$".

[See this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) for more.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.